# ASP.net MVC 4 (web api) OData Configuration

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api

Been playing around with the (Single Page App) [BigShelf](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/spa-samples) sample. I found really interesting is the GetBooksForSearch method (/api/BigShelf/GetBooksForSearch) that it takes additional `$filter`, `$inlinecount`, `$top`, `$skip` parameters for paging and filtering results, which are not present in the controller code:

```
public IQueryable<Book> GetBooksForSearch
    (string profileIds, Sort sort, bool sortAscending)
```

I coudln't find any documents about how that Controller translate and filter the result afterwards and more importantly, how to configure such behavior (e.g., limit the max result), anyone have a clue?

-- Updated --

Found out that MVC Web API is doing the trick. But how can we configure it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's an action filter attribute called [`ResultLimitAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.resultlimitattribute(v=vs.108).aspx) which you can use on any action method which returns `IQueryable<T>` or even `IEnumerable<T>` to limit the amount of data returned.

```
[ResultLimit(100)]
public IQueryable<Product> Get() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.resultlimitattribute(v=vs.108).aspx) seems to be a new Filter, and I guess this is designed for the new framework and exactly what I want..

Comment: Is there an alternative to using an Attribute? It's just that the number can't be pulled from config since Attributes must use constants.

Comment: @LukePuplett you could try to write a filter attribute that pulls the value from config

Answer (score 14):

It appears that the ResultLimitAttribute has been removed. See this [commit](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/514208701b05)

It was rolled into a feature of the [Queryable] attribute which is now required for OData support. See discussion [here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/350872/)

Proper Usage would now be

`[Queryable(ResultLimit = 10)]`

**[UPDATE]**

As of RTM the ResultLimit feature of Queryable has been removed. Also, [Queryable] has been moved to it's own preview package. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/08/15/asp-net-web-api-released-and-a-preview-of-what-s-next.aspx) blog post for more information and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/08/15/odata-support-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx) post for instructions on the new usage.

**[UPDATE 2 11-16-12]**
With the ASP.Net Fall 2012 Update Preview things have been updated again.
The ResultLimit Property of The [Queryable] attribute has been added back to the OData package.

See article [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/11/asp-net-fall-2012-update-preview-is-out-whats-new-for-web-api-developers/) for a run down of some of the changes.

[Here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.odata) is the updated Nuget package. As of this writing it is a PREVIEW package.

Comment: It looks like ResultLimit was removed by the 5.2 official release. This is now found in EnableQueryAttribute for PageSize.

Answer (score 3):

There is a short webcast about paging and querying with MVC Web API that you can watch [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/video-paging-and-querying)

It explains how you can perform paging by either

- using the OData query syntax, in which case the Web API automatically interprets and retrieves the results for you,
- or by writing your own method which takes as parameters the `pageIndex` and `pageSize`, and then returns the requested number of items.

AFAIK, you cannot configure the maximum number of items returned by using the first method, but you could limit the number of items returned by using the second approach, and just checking `if (pageSize>maxPage) then return maxPage items`.

Comment: There is secret fairy dust under the covers with option 1.  You can just as easily write your own method that only loads the necessary data.  With option 1, the framework is just going to call .Take, .Skip, etc on the IQueryable you return

Comment: @RobertLevy, doing .Take on the IQueryable return is not a good idea, since OData also defines filtering operations. That would makes `IQueryable.Take(n).filter()` instead of `IQueryable.filter().Take(n)`

Answer (score 1):

As Cody Clark pointed out, this area has seen quite a number of changes over time. As of the 5.2 version of WebAPI, you now use the `EnableQueryAnnotation` and use the `PageSize` parameter rather than `QueryableAttribute` or `ResultLimit`. (`[Queryable]` will still work, but it is marked as obsolete.) Currently you would use the following syntax:

```
[EnableQuery(PageSize = 20, MaxTop = 20)]
public IQueryable<Product> Get() {
    // ...
}
```

By using `PageSize`, you set the default page size for unparameterized requests. If you don't include the `MaxTop` value, a rogue client could set the top to a very high value and bypass the page defaults. With `MaxTop`, you will throw an exception if the client requests more records than your API supports.